# Append output at the end of a file - How to?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, loops, foreach, outputstream

The following code outputs the result to a csv file. Lets say there are 10 values in the 'valueDataList' ... When this is run, only one row is outputted to the file. How can I loop through the code to print the file for all values 'at once' in "valueDataList".

```
   foreach (var value in valueDataList)

    {
        var value1 = xxxxxxx    // this value is set here based on a query.. 
        int value2 = xxxxxxxx   // this value is set here based on a query.. 

        byte[] content;

        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())  
           {
              using (var writer = new StreamWriter(ms))
                {
                  writer.WriteLine("ValueHeading1   " + " ValueHeading2");
                  writer.WriteLine(value1 + "              " + value2);                         
                }
                  content = ms.ToArray();
                  return File(content, "text/csv", "demo.csv");
           }
    }
```

Basically I want to be able to append to an existing csv file on each loop iteration. How can I do this? thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean you want to write all rows from valueDataList to a csv-file?
If so;

```
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())  
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(ms))
{
    writer.WriteLine("ValueHeading1   " + " ValueHeading2");

    foreach (var value in valueDataList)
    {
        var value1 = xxxxxxx    // this value is set here based on a query.. 
        int value2 = xxxxxxxx   // this value is set here based on a query.. 

        writer.WriteLine(value1 + "              " + value2);                         
    }   

    byte[] content = ms.ToArray();
    return File(content, "text/csv", "demo.csv");
}
```

Comment: This worked great.. How can I change the file to an excel output for example.

Comment: To create a real excel file is complicated, but if you change your fixed-width approach to semi-colon delimited values and change the file extension to .xls, I think you'll be happy with how Excel opens the file for you. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. yes that is an option.. But I am trying this out.. http://code.google.com/p/excellibrary/     so far its been good progress. I will update after I am done.

Answer (score 0):

What about `File.AppendText(...)`?

I was looking at this for reference:

https://web.archive.org/web/20210417083045/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/072303-1.2.aspx

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. That line of code is returning the file already at that moment. I probably need to append before that line of code.

Comment: Perhaps instead of returning a new file, you should create the file, append to it, and then return it.  I'm no asp guy, so all of this is AFAIK.